# How to create global variable as html

Tags: twig

```
$value = sha1("anything");
$secure = '<input type = "hidden" value = "'.$value.'"/>';
$this->twig->addGlobal('anything',$secure);
```

After this I access this variable like this on template
`{{ anything }}`
The big surprise print this variable don't escaped like this
`<input type = "hidden" value = "8867c88b56e0bfb82cffaf15a66bc8d107d6754a"/>`
I want to print as html tag. But it worked when I used `{{ anything|raw }}`, I wish it worked without using `raw` filter

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the variable as safe, without the filter `raw`, if you wrap it in a `Twig\Markup` instance, e.g.

```
$value = sha1("anything");
$secure = new \Twig\Markup('<input type = "hidden" value = "'.$value.'"/>', 'UTF-8');
$this->twig->addGlobal('anything',$secure);
```